# Generic shadows of convex bodies

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

If $K \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is a convex body (i.e., a compact convex set) and $T \mathbin\colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear map then $TK \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex body as well.  Let us say that $T$ has the *uniqueness property* (with respect to $K$) if for each extremal point $y$ of $TK$, there exists a unique point $x \in K$ such that $T(x) = y$. (Such $x$ is necessarily an extremal point of $K$.)

Let $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^m , \mathbb{R}^n) \simeq \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ denote the set of linear maps $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider the following statement:

> **Theorem (putative).** If $n>0$ then for every convex body $K \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ there exists a dense $G_\delta$ subset $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^m , \mathbb{R}^n)$ such that every $T$ in $\mathcal{R}$ has the uniqueness property (w.r.t. $K$).

Is the statement above correct? (It is trivial for $m \le n$.) Does it have a name? (The case $n=1$ is related to Straszewicz's theorem.)

I'm especially interested in versions where $\mathbb{R}^m$ (but not $\mathbb{R}^n$) is replaced by an infinite-dimensional vector space, say separable Banach. (The case $n=1$ is related to a theorem by Stanisław Mazur, 1933.)

Comment: MSN doesn't seem to know about any 1933 publication by Mazur.  Is it the 1935 paper [Auerbach, Mazur, and Ulam - Sur une propriété caractéristique de l'ellipsoïde](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01733278) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1550413))?

Comment: @LSpice That paper is too old for MSN, but it's recorded in Zentralblatt https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0008.31603. According to Ruelle's book Thermodynamical Formalism, p 152, the statement of Mazur's theorem is this: If $V$ is a separable Banach space and $P : V \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex continuous, then the set of points $x \in V$ at which there is only one tangent functional is residual (dense $G_\delta$).